# Javascript: Preventing browser from freezing while calling server

Tags: javascript, progress-indicator

I use jquery to display a progress indicator just prior to calling the server. After the call returns, I hide the progress indicator. The problem I am noticing is that the progress indicator never gets displayed and the browser window freezes until the call to the client returns. How can I prevent this. I want the progress indicator to animate while the call is being carried out.

I am using the $.ajax method to call the server. Here's the code. Note that I am not showing the call to $.ajax as this is buried in the invoke call, but be assured it is called.

```
// Show progess indicator while waiting.
var imgAjaxSaving = $("#imgAjaxSaving");
imgAjaxSaving.show();

// Call server
developerServiceProxy.invoke
("SaveAppSpec",
    { "appSpec": appSpec },
    function (result)
    {
      // Hide the progress indicator.
      imgAjaxSaving.hide();
    },
    AjaxError, false, false
);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to display the progress indicator as well as your ajax call?

Comment: The important bit of code is the $ajax call. What, at least, are the parameters for developerServiceProxy.invoke(...). What are the two false arguments at the end used for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an asynchronous call and use a callback function to hide the progress bar.

Look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also, ensure that async equals true in the options (this is the default).

Comment: Can you confirm that "async" does not equal false in the ajax options.